# Go to next page when webscraping Google

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape the list of hotels that are on Google hotels. However, I cannot figure out a way to bypass the pagination on Google, as the URL stays practically the same, only some things change. See below link and screenshot

[Hotel List Dublin on Google](https://www.google.com/travel/hotels?hrf=CgUIrAIQACIDRVVSKhYKBwjjDxAMGBMSBwjjDxAMGBQYASgAsAEAWAFoAZoBLhIGRHVibGluGiQweDQ4NjcwZTgwZWEyN2FjMmY6MHhhMDBjN2E5OTczMTcxYTCiARIKCC9tLzAyY2Z0EgZEdWJsaW6qAQoKAgghEgIIFRgBqgEWCgIIHBICCAcSAghREgIIRxICCDYYAaoBCgoCCCUSAgh3GAGqARIKAggREgIIKhICCDgSAggCGAGqARcKAgguEgIIPBICCDsSAwiBARICCCcYAaoBCgoCCFASAghPGAGqAQwKAwijARIDCKQBGAGSAQIgAQ&tcfs=EiwKCC9tLzAyY2Z0EgZEdWJsaW4aGAoKMjAxOS0xMi0xORIKMjAxOS0xMi0yMFIA&rp=aAE4AUgC&destination=Dublin&ap=EgAwA2gA)

[image: The only change I noticed in the URL]

I was wondering if anyone on here has passed this issue before?

I have successfully scraped the data from the 1st page, but I need to do it for every page that is there

See below for my current code. I have commented out the next page part, as I do not know how to get it to work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html


url = f"https://www.google.com/travel/hotels?hrf=CgUIrAIQACIDRVVSKhYKBwjjDxAMGBMSBwjjDxAMGBQYASgAsAEAWAFoAZoBLhIGRHVibGluGiQweDQ4NjcwZTgwZWEyN2FjMmY6MHhhMDBjN2E5OTczMTcxYTCiARIKCC9tLzAyY2Z0EgZEdWJsaW6qAQoKAgghEgIIFRgBqgEWCgIIHBICCAcSAghREgIIRxICCDYYAaoBCgoCCCUSAgh3GAGqARIKAggREgIIKhICCDgSAggCGAGqARcKAgguEgIIPBICCDsSAwiBARICCCcYAaoBCgoCCFASAghPGAGqAQwKAwijARIDCKQBGAE&tcfs=EiwKCC9tLzAyY2Z0EgZEdWJsaW4aGAoKMjAxOS0xMi0xORIKMjAxOS0xMi0yMFIA&rp=aAFIAg&destination=Dublin&ap=MABoAA"


data = {
    'name': [],
    'star': [],
    'rating': [],
    'reviews': [],
    'price': []
}

def export(data):
    table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name','rating','reviews','star','price'])
    table.to_csv('Listings.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', index=False)

def getHotel(hotel):
    name = hotel.find(class_='BgYkof ogfYpf ykx2he').get_text()
    star = hotel.find(class_='sSHqwe r10jJf').get_text()
    rating = hotel.find(class_='sSHqwe').get_text()
    reviews = hotel.find(class_='sSHqwe uTUoTb fOuaIb XLC8M').get_text()
    price = hotel.find(class_='A9rngd wNqaKc idHpEf').get_text()

    data['name'].append(name.strip())
    data['star'].append(star.strip())
    data['rating'].append(rating.strip())
    data['reviews'].append(reviews.strip())
    data['price'].append(price.strip())

    export(data)

#def parse_page(url):
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

hotels = soup.findAll(class_='f1dFQe')

for hotel in hotels:
    getHotel(hotel)

    # next_page_text = soup.find(class_='RveJvd snByac').text
    # print(next_page_text)
    # if next_page_text == 'Next':
    #     next_page_url = soup.find('a', class_='nextprev_on')['href']
    #     print(next_page_url)
    #     parse_page(url)
    # else:
    #     export(data)

#parse_page(url)
```

Below is a screenshot of the HTML for the button on the web page

[image: HTML Code on Google for Next Button]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the next page url and then request and parse it. It looks like you have commented out code that would do that. The issue is that you are relying on obfuscated class names. You might have more consistent results going with their elements. To close, I've had a better and more manageable experience using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Updating my answer in regard to your comment:
I noticed that `jsname` is kept as one paginates: `$('div[jsname="WUPT1e"]')` gets the button but Google intentionally codes it in such a way that it is hard to just parse for the generated URL. Beautiful Soup and the requests libraries don't interact with a page. You will need a headless web driver that can interact with AJAX. I would suggest to run the first URL through a proxy to grab the generated URLs for the next page results and then parse the grabbed URLs with Beautiful Soup and the requests.

Searching for 'Scrapy' and 'Selenium' should return results that will help. To get you started: https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-a-simple-way-to-start-scrapy-and-selenium-part-i-10367164c6c0

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have added a screenshot of the HTML where the button is. There is not much from what I can see that I would be able to parse it

Comment: Updated answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, Im really new to all of this, would you have some sort of guide on how to do this?

Comment: Added tutorial link.